# ViewModel unexpected onCleared() call

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewmodel, android-lifecycle, android-viewmodel

I have a viewpager with 10+ pages in it, each page corresponds to its `PageFragment` and `PageViewModel` instances. When I start to swipe fragments one after another the `onCleared()` method is called for viewmodel that was left behind 2-3 steps ago, for example when I'm on page 7 the 4-th viewmodel is destroyed. The problem is, when I reach position 8-10 the `onCleared()` method starts to trigger also for this active viewmodel, which results to bad data representation on screen. Official documentation says that `onCleared()` is called whenever the viewmodel is not used anymore and should be destroyed, but how should it be destroyed if its  data is represented on the active fragment

I tried to find any info about `onCleared()` method, but found almost nothing. Stack trace contains nothing suspicious. I presume that there is a force lifecycle methods call mechanism, but possible causes of its intervention in my case are unknown to me.

Please share your thoughts why is this behavior happening and how could I fix it.

Comment: Which which fragment or activity you have attached the viewModel lifecycle ?

Comment: @AshutoshOjha, the corresponding PageFragment initializes the viewmodel